# How to detect a .p7m file content-type, magic number and extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, digital-signature

Trying to detect a signed file doesn't gives back the right extension and content type:

```java
    byte[] content = parameters.getBytes();

    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    try {

        InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(content, metadata);
        MediaType mediaType = config.getMimeRepository().detect(stream, metadata);

        MimeType mimeType = config.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
        String extension = mimeType.getExtension();

    } catch (IOException | MimeTypeException e) { return false; }
```

While doing that through tika API there's no problem with files such as `PDF` or `JPG`,
was easy to find the magic number in order to check the autenticity of the file, there's no much documentation around `P7M` and can't find it's magic number.

Some attempts on the right file that i needed to test gave back a `.dbf` instead of a `.p7m` and others on example files on the internet were detected as `application/pkcs7-signature` with the `.p7s` extension, but that wasn't right.

Shall i use other libraries (even though i would rather use either `Tika` or `BouncyCastle`)?

Did i messed up something on the code?

Comment: Hi, i'm using Tika.detect API and some p7m files are detected as application/x-dbf

Comment: yes, that was the problem, can't show the code but solved with some walkaround

Comment: can you share somerhing useful?

Comment: What do u need? Anyway, I found a sign removal method (aka return the original document binaries) that can be used to check the triplet (application/content, magic number and extension) of the p7m as pdf (original binaries have to give back a. pdf) then checked signature through BouncyCastle libraries

Comment: For the detection used Tika